# Is connecting to an SQL server over LAN from VIsual Stuios "Add Connections" all it takes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, database-connection

after I have placed my database in an sql server
I then need to modify my connections from `data connections` in `server explorer` 
but how do i add a connection to the sql server oner the LAN

**this is a random screenshot so though it may say "Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB)" it is really Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)**

the database i wish to connect to is located on a different computer

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the "Data Source" to "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)" using the button "Change".

Enter your credentials.

Press "Test Connection".

EDIT:

The Sql Server computer has to have several things done to it to allow remote connections.

Here is a full write up:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Note, if that article does not exist in the future......just google "enable remote connections sql server" and you'll find multiple articles.

Comment: I edited the question to point out that i'm connecting to the SQL server on another computer . still,thanks for the response .

Comment: In the modify connection area I need to select `ActiveSync Connected Device` dont I ?

Comment: the SQL server does allow remote connections . am I just over thinking things here  because i'm wondering what needs to be done on my end where my vb application with its database is concerned

Comment: There are multiple steps to actually get remote_connections to work.  "Allow Remote Connections" (the checkbox) is only one of them.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  If the Sql Server is setup (completely) for allowing remote access AND you have the correct credentials......the VS part of it should be trivial.